# Reservation data model for Entity Framework (code-first)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, datamodel

I could use help and advice how I should create my data model that I'm going to use in my project.

It's a project where I'm going to create a hotel application where you can make a reservation for a room.

I want 3 model classes:

- BookingModel (holds all created bookings)
- RoomModel (holds all the rooms)
- PersonDetailsModel (the person who ordered the booking)

I'm a little unsure how my data model should be... have made these terms that I have thought about.

- A booking can have 1 to many rooms.
- A room can be booked many times, but at different days.
- A booking can be booked by a single person.

I guess that we have a many-to-many relationship between booking and room? And a many to 1 between booking and person?

Code (Models):

```
public class Booking
{
    public int BookingID{ get; set; }
    public string BookingNumber{ get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckInDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckOutDate { get; set; }
    public int PersonDetailsID { get; set; }

    public virtual PersonsDetails PersonsDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
} 

public class PersonDetails
{
    public int PersonDetailsID{ get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
} 

public class Room
{
    public int RoomID{ get; set; }
    public string RoomNumber{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings{ get; set; }
}
```

This is how my models looks now. Have not sure if Booking should have for foreign key to PersonDetails or the other way around (persondetails should have bookingID as foreign key)

Any suggestions I have missed?

Comment: have you seen my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Have not sure if Booking should have for foreign key to PersonDetails or the other way around (persondetails should have bookingID as foreign key)

Booking is made by one person and a person can made multiple bookings. Then your model is correct because :

- with navigation property `PersonalDetails`on `Booking` class we can know who made it.
- you can also add a collection navigational property `ICollection<Booking>` in `PersonalDetails` if you need to know all booking related to a specific person.